# Freehand drawing Gtk / set_event_compression(false) does not work

Tags: events, gtk, drawing, gtk3, gtkmm

I'm developing a graphic software with GTK+ (gtkmm) and want to build a free hand drawing feature.

I connect to the `signal_motion_notify_event` on a `Gtk::EventBox` and set `set_event_compression` to `false` on the event box. I also set `set_event_compression(false)` on the window containing the event box, but nothing seems to work. The program is not running so fluently that it would allow drawn trough lines, instead I get multiple single dots or short dashes.

I also tried using `Gdk::Window::get_pointer(int,int,Gdk::ModifierType)` in an extra `thread`, but this doesn't work either (no drawn through lines also).

Here is some example code to illustrate (I use `Gtk::Image`-class to draw the a pixbuf):

Toolbox.cc

```cpp
// eb means EventBox
Gtk::EventBox& eb = drawingWin->getEventBox();
eb.signal_motion_notify_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(image, &Image::motionEvent));
```

DrawingWindow.cc

```cpp
DrawingWindow::DrawingWindow(int x, int y) : area(x, y), background("/home/tux/Pictures/Arch_Linux_Wallpaper_by_james66.jpg")
{
    // eb means EventBox
    eb.get_window()->set_event_compression(false);
}
```

Image.cc

```cpp
bool Image::motionEvent(_GdkEventMotion* event)
{
    if(event)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        //custom set_pixel function on Gdk::Pixbuf using guint8* Gdk::Pixbuf::get_pixels() const
        this->set_pixel(event->x, event->y, 0x000000ff);
        //updates the Gtk::Image by calling Gtk::Image::set(Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>)
        this->_udpate();
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you give a look to the `GtkDrawingArea` sample in `gtk3-demo` ? I think it has the same limitations, but maybe you could learn from the code. I also wonder why you're using a `GtkEventBox`, as a `GtkDrawingArea` should have everything you need. About using threads, don't. GTK+ is not thread-safe, so you can't draw outside of the main thread.

Comment: @liberforce I used a Gtk::Image and not a Gtk::DrawingArea, but with a Gdk::Pixbuf to draw everything. Don't know if this is the reason why the event dispatch is so slow.
I used the Glib::Dispatcher class to handle the update of the Image (also noticed GTK+ is not threadsafe).

Comment: @liberforce I gues you mean https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/drawingarea.c. I tested the code and also added `gdk_window_set_event_compression(drawingarea_gdk_window, FALSE)`, but it did not help. No drawn through lines either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should ask your question on the GTK+ IRC.

Answer (score 0):

In GIMP (the program GTK+ was originally written for) there are gaps between single points too, if the mouse is moved too quickly, which are filled with straight lines between the points.

In GTK+ and gtkmm there are [`Gdk::EventMask`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/group__gdkmmEnums.html#ga0288c23e93ded8c0326235f1f1120c61)s. These can be set with [`Gtk::Widget::set_events(Gdk::EventMask)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#adeb38a3d5988a0e31055bbd2edb2e954). One needs to make sure that `POINTER_MOTION_MASK` is set (not `POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK`).

One also needs to make sure, that event-compression is disabled. Until including GTK3 this could be done using [`Gdk::Window::set_event_compression(false)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Window.html#a96ff108c0f44adc8d820ac7e485725b0)

In GTK4 event-compression is always turned on:

> With GTK4 one needs to look at the event history between motion events to reconstruct the ones that where coalesced. In gtk4 event delivery rate is fixed to run by the frame clock (that is, 60hz). *`get_motion_history()`* (function name may have changed) will only return the motion coordinates that were accumulated during the handling of that frame.

Here are two examples:

1. [`gtk3-demo`](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/drawingarea.c)
2. [PyGtk2](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/scribblesimple.py) (one needs to have `python2`, `pygtk2` and `gtk2` installed to test this.

All of these examples lack coherence (there are gaps between the lines).

**It's not possible building choerent free hand drawing using GTK+ without interpolation!**

There is also an [example using Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html), which is coherent:
[Qt5 Scribble](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html)

Comment: In Gtk+3.0 (3.22.30) event compression is on by default.

Comment: and docs say: "Since GTK 3.8, motion events are already compressed by default"